# Two dependent filters in R Shiny with a DataTable

Tags: r, filter, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I have two problems:

I have two dependent filters in the database, and I want to search either by player or by their ID. I also want the first filter (SelectInput) to be responsive.

If for example I enter the number 2 in the ID, I want my selectInput to display Lionel Messi automatically.

Here is the code and thank you for your answers

```
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

Database<- data.frame(Player=c("Cristiano Ronaldo","Lionel Messi","Neymar Jr","Cristiano Ronaldo"),ID=c(1,2,3,1))

ui<-dashboardPage(title="Application",skin="red",
                  dashboardHeader(),
                  dashboardSidebar(),
                  dashboardBody(
                    selectInput("player",HTML('Please select your player'),choices=names(table(Database$Player))),
                    searchInput(inputId = "IDSEARCH", label = HTML('Or Please write the ID player'),
                      #placeholder = "13850",
                      btnSearch = icon("search"),
                      btnReset = icon("remove"),
                      width = "500px"),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("mtable2")
                    ))





server <- function(input, output){
  mtable2 <- reactive({filter(Database,(Player==input$player|ID==input$IDSEARCH))})
 output$mtable2<-DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(mtable2())})
    
    
    
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Did you specify all the relevant packages? I suspect you are missing at least `dplyr` and `shinyWidgets`?

Comment: Thank you, i modified it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution to your problem. After the code I explain several things there.

```r
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

Database <- data.frame(
  Player = c("Cristiano Ronaldo", "Lionel Messi", "Neymar Jr", "Cristiano Ronaldo"),
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 1), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- dashboardPage(title = "Application", skin = "red",
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    selectInput(
    inputId = "player", 
    label = "Please select your player",
      choices = unique(Database$Player)
    ),
    searchInput(
      inputId = "id", 
      label = "Or Please write the ID player",
      btnSearch = icon("search"),
      btnReset = icon("remove"),
      width = "500px"
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mtable2")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mtable2 <- reactive({
    if (!isTruthy(input$id)) {
      idx <- Database$Player == input$player
    } else {
      idx <- Database$ID == input$id
    }
    Database[idx, ]
  })
  
  output$mtable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtable2())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$id, {
    req(input$id)
    selected_plyr <- unique(Database[Database$ID == input$id, ]$Player)
    
    if (length(selected_plyr) == 0) {
      showNotification("There is no player for the given ID", type = "error")
      req(FALSE)
    }
    
    if (length(selected_plyr) > 1) {
      showNotification("There is more than one player for a given ID", type = "error")
      req(FALSE)
    }
    
    updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "player",
      selected = selected_plyr
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

1. There is no need to wrap the input labels within `HTML()`.
2. I've slightly modified how you pick the choices for the `selectInput()`. Note the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the data frame (in R >= 4.0.0 this is not needed).
3. I wouldn't use a `searchInput` for the ID, but since it was your choice I'm keeping it here.
4. The `isTruthy()` function checks whether the value in `input$id` is "truthy" as the name says. Basically it checks it is not NULL, empty string, NA, etc. So, when no ID is given, we use the name in the `selectInput()` to filter.
5. The filtering could be done with {dplyr} but it is also very easy with base R (just subset notation `Database[idx, ]`.
6. I added an observer to `input$id` that updates the `selectInput()`. Note you need to pass the `session`, which becomes an argument to your server function...

Well, just feel free to ask if you have any questions!

EDIT:

To use {dplyr} I would change the following

```r
    if (!isTruthy(input$id)) {
      idx <- Database$Player == input$player
    } else {
      idx <- Database$ID == input$id
    }
    Database[idx, ]
```

would be rewritten as

```r
    if (!isTruthy(input$id)) {
      Database %>% filter(Player == input$player)
    } else {
      Database %>% filter(ID == input$id)
    }
```

and replace

```r
selected_plyr <- unique(Database[Database$ID == input$id, ]$Player)
```

with

```r
selected_plyr <- Database %>% filter(ID == input$id) %>% pull(Player) %>% unique()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !

and, if we want to use dplyr instead of Base R, how should we do ? It's just to have an idea

Thank you very much

Comment: See Edit  please :)